# How to create a signed Android application?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

This is my first android app that I would want to publish in the Google Play Store. I have followed the steps from [this article](http://www.programmingodyssey.com/2013/01/create-signed-android-application-using.html).

However I get stuck at one step for specifying the keystore selection. Using the use existing keystore my path

> C:\Users\joyson.android\debug.keystore

I suppose this is the `debug.keystore` which cannot be used for publishing the app. Can someone please suggest how can I do this? Gone through most of the links however the one above was simple and straightforward. Also I am using **Eclipse** Tool. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this tutorial about [Build Android application package file (APK) using Eclipse IDE and Android Developer Tools (ADT) Plugin](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/23/build-android-application-package-file-apk-using-eclipse-ide-and-android-development-tools-adt-plugin). In here describe how to Create new keystore.

Comment: Thanks Bishan.I need to ask some more questions.Do i need to manually set the debug==false in manifest?as of now i havent set the debuggable property.Also how can i know whether all the requirements have been fulfilled for my app to be published.What are the other requirements foe publishing my app?

Comment: Yes. Make sure you deactivate logging and disable the debugging option before you build your application for release. Read this article about [Preparing for Release](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the "Create New Keystore" option if you are signing that application for the first time. Provide the details as described in the link and you will get signed APK in the end.

Answer (score 0):

File->Export->Android Application

Select Which project to be exported

Then click Next

Create New Keystore and fill it. Specify particular location where your keystore to get generated.

And finally it will ask where to save apk file.Specify the location

It will be your signed apk. Remember your password forever for next updates